# accessing component functions in shared modules

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, shared-module

I have a shared module that contains common components such as headers and notification components. I have a another module called ProductModule which uses the notification component from the shared module and calls a function defined in the notification component.

**shared.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        HeaderComponent,
        SideNavComponent,
        SpinnerComponent,
        ItemSummaryComponent,
        UserRoleDirective,
        EmptyResultComponent,
        NotificationComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatIconModule
    ],
    exports: [
        HeaderComponent,
        SideNavComponent,
        SpinnerComponent,
        ItemSummaryComponent,
        EmptyResultComponent,
        NotificationComponent
    ],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

**notification.component.ts**

```
export class NotificationComponent {
  openSnackBar(message: string, state: string, icon: string): void {
    const config = new MatSnackBarConfig();
    config.duration = 3000;
    config.panelClass = ['nc-notification', state];
    config.data = { message, icon };
    this._snackBar.openFromComponent(NotificationComponent, config);
  }
}
```

In my lazy loaded `productModuel`, I have imported my `sharedModule` as below.

```
import { CommonCmpsModule } from '../common-cmps/common-cmps.module';
import { TaxConfigurationComponent } from './tax-configuration/tax-configuration.component';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        TaxConfigurationComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        SharedModule,
      ]
    })
    export class ProductModule { }
```

In my `TaxConfigurationComponent`, I want to use the notification component and call the openSnackBar function.

TaxConfiguration.component.ts

```
import { NotificationComponent } from 'src/app/common-cmps/notification/notification.component';

export class TaxConfigurationComponent {
    constructor(
        private notificationService: NotificationService
    ){}

    onClickSave(): void {
        this.notificationService.openSnackBar('An Error Occurred', 'nc-notification--error', 'close');
    }
}
```

But, I'm getting below error in the browser console.

***ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(ProductManagementModule)[NotificationComponent -> NotificationComponent -> NotificationComponent -> NotificationComponent]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for NotificationComponent!***

Answer (score 0):

constructor is used for injecting services not component.

For a component there are two options you have.

1. if selector is used, you can use @ViewChild to get notification component instance and call the method.
2. if selector is not used, create a service with a subject and call .next on that subject from taxconfiguration component. subscribe that subject in notification component and call your opensnackbar method inside subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use constructor injection for the component. In tax configuration component you are using

```
 constructor(
        private notificationCmp: NotificationComponent
    ){}
```

please remove that.
And inject `MatSnackBar` service which is provided by material like below

```
import {MatSnackBar} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
constructor(private _snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}
```

this and use your custom component like below

```
  this._snackBar.openFromComponent(NotificationComponent, {
      duration: 1500,
    });
```

Other than that u need to add NotificationComponent as an entry component inside the model

```
  entryComponents: [NotificationComponent],
```

Comment: I have used this before and do not want to add multiple openFromCompinent from every component I use.

Answer (score 0):

Could the issue be that you are importing **NotificationComponent** but in constructor you are referencing **NotificationService** and trying to call the function defined in **NotificationComponent** ?